# Problem with mon0 interface

Tags: aircrack-ng

Please I have problem on my `mon0` interface I try different ways but still couldn't fix it. I want to turn on `mon0`. and here is the outcome.

```
# airmon-ng start wlan0

Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
722 avahi-daemon
730 avahi-daemon
775 NetworkManager
834 wpa_supplicant


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Broadcom    wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
                        (monitor mode enabled on mon0)


# airodump-ng mon0
Interface mon0: 
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device
root@mbfada-Lenovo-G400:/opt/aircrack-ng# airodump-ng wlan0
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Operation not supported

ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.  Make
sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start wlan0 <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found either.


# airmon-ng start wlan0

Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
722 avahi-daemon
730 avahi-daemon
775 NetworkManager
834 wpa_supplicant


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Broadcom    wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
                        (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

Comment: Try stopping processes that may cause problems: `sudo stop avahi-daemon` , `sudo stop network-manager` and  `killall wpa_supplicant` if it is still running. Could you post your driver info `lshw -C network`.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to include the output of: `lspci -nn | grep -i net`.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu's network manager is conflicting. You can turn set it to manual using

```
sudo stop network-manager
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override
```

After that you should be able to run

```
sudo airodump-ng start wlan0
```

Alternatively, you could also set

```
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlan0;interface-name:mon0
```

or for a hw address

```
unmanaged-devices=mac:11:22:33:44:55:66
```

This can be changed in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf under section keyfile. See also

```
man NetworkManager.conf
```

Comment: Instead of disabling Network Manager completely, one could also set `unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlan0;interface-name:mon0` (or `unmanaged-devices=mac:11:22:33:44:55:66` for a hw addr). This can be changed in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` under section `keyfile`. See also `man NetworkManager.conf`.

Comment: Arguably the better solution, i'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply killing the processes works. You shouldn't need to unmanage the interface:

As an example:

```
kill 722 730 775 834
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

The numbers (pid in the `kill`) will be different most of the times.